# What represents the storage computing in Android

Tags: android, storage

I have two related questions about Android Pie:

1: When I go to Settings->Storage, I see that they display the memory used (3.12 GB in my 1st picture). In the code, I see that this number comes from /data partition as seen here: 
http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/StorageStatsService.java#217
with `path.getUsableSpace();` where `path = "/data"`
However, when I go to /data partition with the cmd line and I type "du -sh" it displays 2.7GB. Why there is this difference?

[image]

2: Below, there is a list of all sections with memory used in these sections. I can see in Other apps in my 2nd picture that 5.4GB has be used...which is more than the 3.12GB representing the memory used! How is it possible?

[image]

Comment: wrong community for this, it isn't related to programming or code

Comment: Yes it is (For AOSP developpers). I modified my question so that it is clearer